# How do I attach a reactive-var to a child template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I tried the standard way, but what happens is that currentOdds of all the child templates receive the value given to the reactive-var in the last child template created. o.O

Is this a bug of Meteor? This is how I did it:

```
Template.ChildTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  instance = this;

  odds = ... (dynamically generated)
  instance.currentOdds = new ReactiveVar(odds);
});
```

Comment: What does `odds` hold? Is that another `ReactiveVar`? What is the intended scope for `odds`? You (maybe) forgot to add `var`, `let`

Comment: `var odds = ChecksCollection.findOne().oddsChecked[instance.data.arrayIndex];               ` (Mersi pentru ajutor!)

Comment: Make sure you declare them inside the scope of that function, so that means `var instance = ...` and `var odds = ...`. Or even better, use `let`

Comment: Yep, I corrected my code in all the places where I was doing that mistake. Thanks for the tip. Btw, do you know any solution for this issue? It's the same code and you'll notice that I've done the correction recommended by you: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't doing anything wrong, the issue I had was because of a bug in Blaze ([1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6111))

There's nothing that we're supposed to to different when attaching a Reactive-Var to a child template, compared to a normal template. It should be done in the same manner.([2](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/#tmc-reactive-data-storage))